# Laravel: Storage::drive() and Storage::read()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I saw these `Storage::drive()` and `Storage::read()` in a Laravel 5.1 project, and I cannot find any info of these 2 on the internet.

can somehow explain or post the structure of these methods here?

Comment: i believe drive() and read() is the extend / macro function just for that project. it might be drive() refer to disk() and read() refer to get(). Refer here for 5.1 Illuminate FileSystem https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem/blob/5.1/Filesystem.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Storage` Facade is for `\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager`.

When you are calling `Storage::drive()` Laravel are calling a instance of
`\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager` with the `drive()` method behind the scenes.

However, the `read()` method does not exist on the `FilesystemManager` directly.
It exists on another class `\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem`.
When calling a method on the `FilesystemManager` that does not exist. PHP will use the magic method `__call()` inside of the `FilesystemManager`. Which in this case redirects the call to the `Filesystem::drive()` method.

So a `Storage::read()` is more or less the same as a `$filesystemManager->drive()->read()`.

You can find some api documentation here.
https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.html
https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html

You can also find some Facade documentation here.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades

Answer (score 0):

**In Laravel 5.6 see Filesystem.php localted at:** \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php
where you can read add available function for Storage facade.

I will suggest you to instead of searching on internet try to search and explore from framework first. If you still stuck to find a solution then go to internet.